# Why is Ubuntu taking so long to login?

Tags: boot, login

I am new to Ubuntu, and I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a Desktop environment.

I have noticed that Ubuntu is taking like 3-4 seconds to show the desktop after I enter my password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I have checked for the startup applications but there are no such applications that can cause this delay.

Boot takes normal time (around 10 seconds). My laptop has Intel HD 620 graphics and I'm using that only.

Comment: Oh so sorry I have updated it now.

Comment: did you ever use Windows? It takes like 20 seconds before its useable after entering the password. I consider 3-4 seconds quite good. Best option to speed up loading times is a Fast SSD and lots of RAM. Your graphic card is not of any importance for loading times, but it gives a hint that you have a rather low-end PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite normal to have a few seconds of waiting time before your desktop is up and running after login. Your computer is not quite ready once the login appears. The user's desktop is being loaded and prepared only after login, not before, which is why Ubuntu needs some time. "So long" is a very subjective term. Many other users will consider 3 seconds very acceptable.